# Calling apoc.export.graphml.query generates IllegalStateException in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm using the neo4J APOC library, and using the export/import functionality.

apoc.export.graphml.all works great, and is able to extract everything it once, however, when the query version is called, it is not able to do so.
The same is the case with cypher exports.

The error that turns up is `Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed`

```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.export.cypher.query`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Constraint is associated with relationships
```

A query that I tried to run:

```
call apoc.export.graphml.query("match (n) return n", "backups/please", {})
```

Should backup all nodes, when it actually gives the above error.

Comment: can you output your `:schema` or create a minimal database setup that reproduces this? Also raise an issue on the apoc repository.

Comment: I'll do that, on the repo and edit my question for the schema. Thanks for the heads up @MichaelHunger